# Winform issue converting values and displaying them

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry my title is a bit vague, but what I'm trying to do will probably take a paragraph to explain.

At the moment what I'm trying to do is this:

- Gather user in put a from a text box
- Divide the value entered by 2
- Display this new value on a label

So, to get user values I've done this:

```
  private void userLengthTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _userLength = userLengthTextBox.Text;
    }
```

This is coming in as a string. Then in a new function, I'm converting this string to a single (need it to be a float), calculating half the value entered and then storing it in a new float.

Like so:

```
    _oldTlX = Convert.ToSingle(_userLength);
    _tlX = _oldTlX / 2;
```

Then, when I press a button, I'm trying to get this value to display in a label:

```
 _valueLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(_tlX);
```

However, when I press the button, the value remains at 0. No matter what I put. As far as I can see I've converted the value I need to the correct format needed, but it is still saying I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: How about `double.Parse(...)`? And is it correct that the two of your code have different variable names? `_userLength` vs `_userCaveLength`

Comment: Thanks for point out the mistake there (trying to keep variable names simple for the post :) ) Where would I put the double.Parse? In the button press?

Comment: So *where* do you put `Convert.ToSingle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use double internally, and then use a format string to show the result in a propper way:

```
double _oldTlX;
if (!double.TryParse(_userLength, out _oldTlX)) return;
double _tlX = _oldTlX / 2;

_valueLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f3}", _tlX); // 3 decimal positions
```

You can also check at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) how to format numeric results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Remember to protect the double.Parse() ` or use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)